# Can't seem to save database tables in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2012

I know there is supposed to be an 'Update' button rather than a save button like they used to have in 2010. But I've literally been searching for 2 hours and I can't seem to find the button, even after searching the forums. Alt+shift+u doesn't seem to work also. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the screen you are working on?

Comment: The answer below assumes your using SSDT. I'm trying to save in the sever explorer using a data connection (I think @HtusaAdssad is doing the same). I'm sure there's a bug in VS2012 as when I modify and save nothing happens. When I re-open the data table definition my prev changes are lost. I'm not sure if the original posted is also having this same problem?

Answer (score 5):

Hey you can save your table in .Sql format please refer screen shot[image]

Please refer this link also.[Refer Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/fy685z3w.aspx)

Comment: Check the output window. Any chance this is an update that might cause  data or precision loss? You need to set that option explicitly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833431(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running Visual Studio in Administrator Mode. Then click the Update button at the top of the Table View.